# My navbar links not floating the way I want

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website. For some reason, my navbar isn't being very cooperative. I have set up links to other pages on the site, and have floated them to the right. However, they don't seem to move as far right as I want them to. If I use margin-right or left, then when I resize the browser it isn't responsive. But the float property keeps it responsive even though it stays around the center of my nav. Here's my code:

```css
/* Start Variables */

:root{
    --aa-color: #57C324;
}

/* End Variables */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

/* Start Navbar */

.navbar-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
  padding: 2% 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 8px #888888;
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
}

.leftside{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.rightside{
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}

.options{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.linkhome{
    font-size: 120%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--aa-color);
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.linkmenu{
    font-size: 120%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.linkabout{
    font-size: 120%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.linkfood{
    font-size: 120%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.linkculture{
    font-size: 120%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.linkmenu:hover{
    color: var(--aa-color);
}

.linkabout:hover{
    color: var(--aa-color);
}

.linkfood:hover{
    color: var(--aa-color);
}

.linkculture:hover{
    color: var(--aa-color);
}
```

````html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <nav>
            <div class="navbar-wrapper">
                <div class="leftside">

                </div>
                <div class="rightside">
                    <div class="options">
                        <a href="#" class="linkhome">Home</a>
                        <a href="#" class="linkmenu">Menu</a>
                        <a href="#" class="linkabout">About Us</a>
                        <a href="#" class="linkfood">Our Food</a>
                        <a href="#" class="linkculture">Ethiopian Culture</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```
````

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: So how do you want them to be aligned, it is hard to get that from the question. Also from what I got, check that the parent element `class="options"` occupies the width to the end.

Comment: I wan them to be aligned so that they are at the very edge on the screen on the right side, maybe 10px between Ethiopian Culture and the edge.

Comment: check out my solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this sample, float is not a preferred way of laying out elements in a modern web. Please use flex-box;
The cause of the width to the right is caused by the `padding: 2% 10%;`, which I have modified.

Remove the visual backgrounds.

```
nav{
  width:100%;
}
.navbar-wrapper{
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 8px #888888;
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
}

.leftside{
  background: green; 
  width: 50%;
  height: 10px;
}

.rightside{
    width: 50%;
  background: red;

}

.options{
  background: yellow;
    text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
    display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.linkhome{
    font-size: 120%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--aa-color);
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.linkmenu{
    font-size: 120%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.linkabout{
    font-size: 120%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.linkfood{
    font-size: 120%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.linkculture{
    font-size: 120%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.linkmenu:hover{
    color: var(--aa-color);
}

.linkabout:hover{
    color: var(--aa-color);
}

.linkfood:hover{
    color: var(--aa-color);
}

.linkculture:hover{
    color: var(--aa-color);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
/* Start Variables */

:root{
    --aa-color: #57C324;
}

/* End Variables */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

/* Start Navbar */

.navbar-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
 /* padding: 2% 10%; you need to change padding to position to the right correctly */
  padding: 20px 10px;; 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 8px #888888;
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
}

/* you don't need float
.leftside{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.rightside{
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}*/
.rightside{
/*to position your links to the right*/
    text-align: right; 
}

.options{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.linkhome{
    font-size: 120%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--aa-color);
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    /* if you want all links in one line use inline instead*/
    display: inline; 
}

.linkmenu{
    font-size: 120%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    display: inline;
}

.linkabout{
    font-size: 120%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    display: inline;
}

.linkfood{
    font-size: 120%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    display: inline;
}

.linkculture{
    font-size: 120%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    display: inline;
}

.linkmenu:hover{
    color: var(--aa-color);
}

.linkabout:hover{
    color: var(--aa-color);
}

.linkfood:hover{
    color: var(--aa-color);
}

.linkculture:hover{
    color: var(--aa-color);
}
```

```html
        <nav>
            <div class="navbar-wrapper">
                <div class="leftside">

                </div>
                <div class="rightside">
                    <div class="options">
                        <a href="#" class="linkhome">Home</a>
                        <a href="#" class="linkmenu">Menu</a>
                        <a href="#" class="linkabout">About Us</a>
                        <a href="#" class="linkfood">Our Food</a>
                        <a href="#" class="linkculture">Ethiopian Culture</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: This is awesome, except, it kind of pushes the culture div a bit too far...

Answer (score 0):

```
.options {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: a verbal explanation in addition to code is often helpful